# How to fix the error "the email address is badly formatted" in firebase authentication?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I'm adding reset password in my app, every thing goes ok, but when i it tried to test it a toast showed to me with this message "the email address is badly formatted"?

I tried to change input type to textEmailAddress bud doesn't work

```
public class ResetPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText resetPassword;
    Button resetbtn;
    ProgressBar resetBar;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_password);

      resetPassword =findViewById(R.id.emailreset);
       resetBar = findViewById(R.id.resetbar);
       resetbtn = findViewById(R.id.resetbtn);
        resetBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth.getInstance();


        resetbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                resetBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(resetPassword.toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        resetBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(ResetPasswordActivity.this,"Password sent to your Email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(ResetPasswordActivity.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing:

```
  resetPassword =findViewById(R.id.emailreset);
```

And then:

```
 firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(resetPassword.toString())
```

This means that you're passing the actual view into the call to Firebase, not the value that the user entered.

You're probably looking for:

```
resetPassword.getText().toString()
```